# In linux, how to compare two directories by filename only and get list of results that did not match

Tags: linux, bash, list, comparison, diff

I'd like to know how to compare two directories (not recursively) only by filename (ignore extension) to get the difference.  For example, if I have list A and B, I want to know what is present in A and not in B.

I am currently processing some images. In one directory I have source files with the extension .tiff and in the other directory I have processed files with the extension .png.  The filenames are the same in both directories, but only the extension differs (ex. one file is named foo.tiff in directory A, and it is named foo.png in directory B).

I'm trying to find which files have not yet been processed.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Always be interactive, provide as much info as possible and mention the steps that you tried, provide relevant code that got you bumped. And if an answer addresses your issues click on "accept" to help other SO'ers understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand you correctly you nedd following script:

```
#/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
folder1="/home/vagrant/1 b"
folder2="/home/vagrant/2 a"
ext1="tiff"
ext2="png"


for fullfile in ${folder1}/*.$ext1
do
        #echo "$fullfile fullfile"
        filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
        #echo "$filename file"
        extension="${filename##*.}"
        #echo "$extension ext"
        cleanfilename="${filename%.*}"
        #echo "$cleanfilename base"
        if ! [ -a "${folder2}/$cleanfilename.$ext2" ]
        then
                echo $fullfile
        fi
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

it It shows files present in first folder but absent in second. like this:

```
admin$ mkdir 1
admin$ mkdir 2
admin$ touch 1/1.tiff
admin$ touch 1/2.tiff
admin$ touch 1/3.tiff
admin$ touch 2/1.png
admin$ touch 2/2.png
admin$ vim diff.sh
admin$ chmod +x diff.sh 
admin$ ./diff.sh 
/Users/admin/1/3.tiff
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see this should work, but I am running into a snag.  My directory names have spaces in them (I am escaping them using `\ `), and on line 13 the if statement is splitting the path name into multiple pieces.  I have read that the work around for this is to surround the variable in quotes, but it is not working for me.  For example, I have tried:  `"${folder2}/$cleanfilename.$ext2"` and `$"{folder2}"/$cleanfilename."$ext2"` but it is not working.

Comment: you right that happens because for loop uses spaces as separator. I updated script in answer.

Answer (score 8):

First let's create a helper function:

```
getfiles() { find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c 'for f in "$@"; do basename "${f%.*}"; done' "" {} + | sort; }
```

If you run `getfiles dirname`, it will return a sorted list of files in that directory without the directory's name and without any extension.  The `-maxdepth 1` option means that `find` will not search recursively.

Now, let's compare the files directories `A` and `B`:

```
diff <(getfiles A) <(getfiles B)
```

The output is in the usual `diff` format.  As any of diff's normal options can be used, the output format is quite flexible.

#### Example

Here is a sample directory `A` and `B`, each having one file that the other doesn't have:

```
$ ls */
A/:
bar.png  foo.png  qux.png

B/:
bar.tiff  baz.tiff  foo.tiff
```

The output:

```
$ diff <(getfiles A) <(getfiles B)
1a2
> baz
3d3
< qux
```

The output correctly identifies (a) that `B` has a `baz` file that is not present in `A` and (b) that `A` has a `qux` file that is not present in `B`.

#### Alternative Output

Suppose that we just want to do a one-sided comparison and find what files in `B` are not also in `A`.  In this case, `grep` can be used:

```
$ grep -vxFf <(getfiles A) <(getfiles B)
baz
```

The options used here are:

- `-v` tells `grep` to exclude matching lines
- `-x` tells `grep` to match whole lines only
- `-F` tells `grep` that the patterns are fixed strings, not regular expressions.
- `-f` tells `grep` to get the list of patterns from file or, in this case, the file-like object `<(getfiles A)`.

#### Example With File and Directory Names That Include Spaces

Consider these files:

```
$ ls */
A A/:
1 bar.png  1 foo.png  1 qux.png

B B/:
1 bar.tiff  1 baz.tiff  1 foo.tiff
```

The output:

```
$ diff <(getfiles 'A A') <(getfiles 'B B')
1a2
> 1 baz
3d3
< 1 qux
```

Or,

```
$ grep -vxFf <(getfiles 'A A') <(getfiles 'B B')
1 baz
```

#### Limitation

If any of your file names have newline characters in them, this will give incorrect results.  At least for the `grep` form, this could be extended to the more general case.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps.

> -q   Report only whether the files differ, not the details of the differences.
>   -r   When comparing directories, recursively compare any subdirectories found.

```
diff -qr /dir1 /dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of diff command can do this for you.

```
diff DirA/ DirB/
```